# Most efficient way of getting large std::vector into Swift?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, swift, nsarray, stdvector

I have an Objective-C class that populates a `std:vector` with millions of points. The structure of the vector is:

```
typedef std::vector<CGPoint> CGContour;
typedef std::vector<CGContour> CGContours;
```

So a `CGContour` is a vector of CGPoints and `CGContours` is a vector of the `CGContour` vector.

I need to access this data in a Swift class somehow. I don't want to use an NSArray because it has a huge overhead compared to using vector (it is like 10x as big and slow).

What would be the most efficient way to get millions of CGPoints accessible in Swift from my Objective-C class?

Edit:

I am populating my `CGContours` vector like this:

```
contourVector = CGContours(contours.size());
populatedContourNum = 0


//contours is OpenCV's contours
for( long c = 0; c < contours.size();  c++) {

    if (populatedContourNum >= contourVector.size()) {
        contourVector.resize(contourVector.size() + 1);
    }

    contourVector[populatedContourNum] = CGContour(contours[c].size());

    for( long pointNum = 0; pointNum < contours[c].size(); pointNum++ )
    {
        contourVector[populatedContourNum][pointNum] = CGPointMake(contours[c][pointNum].x * scale,
                                                                         contours[c][pointNum].y * scale);
    }

    populatedContourNum++;

}
```

Comment: You can make use Objective-C++ to make  an ObjC class that wraps a `std::vector`, and exposes its pointer so that it can made into an `Unsafe(Mutable)BufferPointer<CGPoint>` in Swift. It will work, but it'll require some memory memory management, and will fail if the vector's buffer is invalidated

Comment: Thanks! Can you please show an example in an answer?

Comment: Nope, I've never tried it. I'm just giving you a general direction to investigate

Comment: Please show your Objective-C++ code using the types, if you want a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks! I added how I am populating the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts are not clear enough but I will try to show you some example.

First of all, you need to prepare a class which can access your `contourVector`. (I cannot see if it is an instance field or a global variable, if it is an instance field, you may use the existing class.)

---

Create a header for the prepared class, again you may utilize the existing header, but this header needs to be compiled both in C-context and in C++ context. So, if your existing header contains some declaration which cannot be compiled in C-context, you may need separated two headers or some `#if`s.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface YourClass : NSObject

- (NSInteger)contoursSize;
- (NSInteger)contourSizeAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (CGPoint *)contourAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

//...

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

Then add 3 methods to the class specified in the header:

```
#import "YourClass.h"
#import <vector>

typedef std::vector<CGPoint> CGContour;
typedef std::vector<CGContour> CGContours;

static CGContours contourVector;

@implementation YourClass

- (NSInteger)contoursSize {
    return contourVector.size();
}
- (NSInteger)contourSizeAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return contourVector[index].size();
}
- (CGPoint *)contourAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return contourVector[index].data();
}

@end
```

---

Please do not forget to include the header inside your `Project-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "YourClass.h"
```

---

You need to create a Swift side wrapper class, as you cannot create `UnsafeBufferPointer` in Objective-C.

```
class YourClassWrapper {
    let yourInstance = YourClass()

    var count: Int {
        return yourInstance.contoursSize()
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> UnsafeBufferPointer<CGPoint> {
        guard 0..<count ~= index else {fatalError("Index \(index) out of bounds \(0..<count)")}
        let start = yourInstance.contour(at: index)
        let count = yourInstance.contourSize(at: index)
        return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: start, count: count)
    }
}
```

---

With these preparations above, you can access each `CGPoint` as:

```
let wrapper = YourClassWrapper()
let point = wrapper[0][1]
```

Or you can get the pointer to the first element in `CGContour` as:

```
let ptr = wrapper[0].baseAddress!
```

---

You may need to modify some parts to fit this into your actual code. Hope you can make it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll give it a shot soon and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: @OOPer what do you think about exposing this data as a `UnsafeBufferPointer<CGPoint>`? You get all the convenience of conformance to `Collection`, but I haven't tried it myself, so IDK what downsides there might be

Comment: @Alexander, the OP's `contourVector` is a vector of vector and the inner vector is `std::vector<CGPoint>`, so `UnsafeBufferPointer<CGPoint>` would fit for the inner vector (as in my answer). But how do you want to manage the outer vector?

Comment: @OOPer ah, i missed that detail.